# flask url_for TypeError

Tags: python, flask

I have an error when trying to use the url_for method in Flask. I'm not sure what the cause of it because I only follow the Flask quick start. I'm a Java guy with a bit of Python experience and want to learn Flask.

Here's the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 36, in <module>
    print url_for(login)
  File "/home/cobi/Dev/env/flask/latest/flask/helpers.py", line 259, in url_for
    if endpoint[:1] == '.':
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__
```

My code is like this:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/login/<username>')
def login(): pass

with app.test_request_context():
  print url_for(login)
```

I'm have tried both the stable and development version of Flask and the error still occurs. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you and sorry if my English is not very good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) say that `url_for` takes a string, not a function. You also need to provide a username since the route you created requires one.

Do this instead:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    print url_for('login', username='testuser')
```

You are receiving this error because strings have a `__getitem__` method but functions do not.

```
>>> def myfunc():
...     pass
... 
>>> myfunc.__getitem__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> 'myfunc'.__getitem__
<method-wrapper '__getitem__' of str object at 0x10049fde0>
>>>
```

Comment: My bad, you're right. But now another error appeared. 
  `print url_for('login')
  File "/home/cobi/Dev/env/flask/latest/flask/helpers.py", line 296, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/home/cobi/Dev/env/flask/latest/flask/helpers.py", line 289, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/home/cobi/Dev/env/flask/latest/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1607, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('login', {}, None)`

Comment: Your issue is that it expects that the login function has a provided username. Use url_for('login', username='cobicobi') instead.

Comment: Ah I think I got it now. You're right. The `url_for` required to have at least the parameter defined in the endpoint. If I don't define a parameter in the endpoint than the `url_for` will work either with a parameter or not. But if I define a parameter in it, I will also have to provided that parameter in the `url_for` call.